# Цикл по файловой системе

Tags: node.js

Есть каталог и вложенные в него каталоги, которые содержат фотографии, мне необходимо перебрать все файлы в этих каталогах, обработать фотографии и положить в другой каталог, но при этом сохранить структуру. Если каталог один и в нем файлы то это просто сделать:

```
var fs = require('fs')
  , gm = require('gm');

    var data = fs.readdirSync('img');


     data.map(function(item, i, arr) {
       gm('img/' + item)
         .write('opt/' + item, function (err) {
          if (err) console.log(err);
        });

     });
```

Подскажите, как пройтись в цикле так, что бы перебрать и вложенные каталоги, при этом и сохранить эту иерархию

Answer (score 1):

Используйте библиотеку  readDir которая позволяет получить масив файлов во всех каталогах и подкаталогах. Должно работать как и в вашем примере.

```
const readDir = require('readdir');
const gm = require('gm');

const data = readDir.readSync('./images');

data.map((item) => {
 gm(`./images/${item}`)
  .write(`./opt/${item}`, (err) => {
   if (err) console.log(err);
 });
});
```